# How to update multiple rows in cx_Oracle Python

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, cx-oracle, sql-update

In python, after successful connection establishment with an oracle database, I want to retrieve data from the database every 5mins, and I want to update a specific column, which will resemble that data has been pulled out.

I have stored the list of emp_id which have been pulled out in an emp_list and tried update command,

```
emp_list = [123,576, 686, 783]
statement = "UPDATE employee SET close_emp_data = 7 WHERE emp_id in (emp_list)"
curs.execute(statement)
connection.commit()
```

when I execute the code, I encounter the following error, "no such column: data"

P.S. I cannot directly pass the emp_id, as they are dynamic and number of rows being retrieved is not fixed.

Comment: [`cursor.executemany`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#executemany)

Comment: See the cx_Oracle doc [Binding Multiple Values to a SQL WHERE IN Clause](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#binding-multiple-values-to-a-sql-where-in-clause).

Comment: Hi Christopher Jones, this is for select statement, for update statement I can't find anything relevant.

Comment: The same approaches apply for an update statement -- any statement really!